# Converting the nvarchar to int

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have google online this question and for the life of me couldn't figure out why this kept throwing errors, any help is appreciated.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT @orderid
>   = t.orderid FROM  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY creationdatetime DESC) AS row FROM
>   [intranet].[dbo].handbook_appendix_data WHERE id = ' to data type int.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @table varchar(40)
SET @table = 'handbook_section_data';
SET @table = 'handbook_appendix_data';

DECLARE @parentid INT
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @published INT
DECLARE @orderid INT
SET @parentid = 2
SET @id = -1
SET @published = 1

SET @sql = N'SELECT @orderid = t.orderid FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY creationdatetime DESC) AS row FROM [intranet].[dbo].'+@table+' WHERE id = '+@id+' AND published = '+@published+') AS t
WHERE t.published = '+@published+' AND t.row = 1';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, N'@orderid INT OUTPUT', @orderid = @orderid OUTPUT --Get the OrderID from ID

PRINT @orderid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your `@id` and `@published` ints to a varchar

```
 convert(varchar(50),@published)
```

ie

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT @orderid = t.orderid FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY creationdatetime DESC) AS row FROM [intranet].[dbo].'+@table+' WHERE id = '+     convert(varchar(50),@id) +' AND published = '+     convert(varchar(50),@published) +') AS t
WHERE t.published = '+convert(varchar(50), @published) +' AND t.row = 1';
```

A better solution would be to avoid the string concatenation, and pass the `@id` and `@published` parameters using the `sp_executesql` as you are already doing with `@orderid`, or to question the requirement for dynamic SQL at all?

Comment: I used dynamic so I could have multiple tables which had the same structure to separate data out, it's only an internal system nothing major.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the integer variables to a character type:

```
 ....
 WHERE id =' + cast(@id as varchar(32)) + ' AND published = ' + cast(@published as varchar(32)) + ') AS t ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE t.published = '+@published+' AND t.row = 1'`

`@published` is an `int`. SQL Server has decided that `+` must be between two `int`s, and is trying to convert the string to an `int`.

To stop this, force `@published` to be a string instead - then it's adding two strings (concatenation) instead:

`WHERE t.published = '+CONVERT(varchar(10),@published)+' AND t.row = 1'`